# VS is storing my data in some other database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Visual studio creates a new database out of thin air to store my data. This is my DbContext:

```
public class LinkedDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LinkedData> LinkedData { get; set; }
}
```

No errors are being thrown, I just end up with another database that is only visible through the SQL Server Object Explorer unlike my initially created database which is the top one in the screenshot.

[image]

**Edit**

I migrated the whole accounts database generated by the MVC project to the MSSQL 2014 server. I simply added a database there and changed the connection string, then it automaticaly populated the database with the needed tables.

So I created my custom table, exactly as it was in the local database. I removed the local databases, the other connection strings and the Controller. Then I rebuild my project and created the controller again. But VS/MVC/EF or whomever is responsible is still creating a local database for my custom data.

When I create the controller it seems to find my table in MSSQL SERVER 2014, otherwise I would get a safe dialogue to store the sql file locally. So what is really happening here? Like I said, the account functionality worked instantly like a charm. My custom table in MSSQL simply won't get used.

**EDIT**

So I set the `DefaultConnectionFactory` in `Web.config` to my MSSQL SERVER 2014 and now it is generating a new Database inside my MSSQL SERVER. It seems to be the namespace, when I create a controller I need to pass in the namespace for the both the Model class and Context class.

```
Model class: LinkedData (DataVisualization.Models)
Data context class: LinkedDataContext (DataVisualization.Models)
```

The databases that keep getting generated automatically to hold my custom data are called: `DataVisualization.Model.LinkedDataContext`.

Does anyone have any idea what is really going on here?

Comment: Which code here is MVC related in any means? RUnning code does not make a question MVC specific, and I fail to see a single line here that is relevant to the question that is MVC specific. Did you consider debugging?

Comment: @TomTom Well, I add a Model and a controller which creates a view. That is shorthand for MVC. I'm not getting any errors, it just creates a new DB like you can see in the screenshot and whenever I create records it is storing them there, instead of the database that is "supposed" to hold the data.

Comment: It does not matter as the "view" is "just a class" (at least the type relevant for the question) and you do nothing with the controller. You can easily copy/paste the relevant code into a command line application - the question stays 100% the same. Ergo you fail to provide a code example as per site rules (shortest code possible). Which would NOT include asp.net as you have zero asp.net specific things that are RELEVANT for the question. Ergo voting to close.

Comment: @TomTom Other than (maybe) some incorrect tags, I don't see what's wrong with the question. Rather than closing, just remove the incorrect tags.

Comment: @tomtom This is all I do... I explain step by step from the point I created a new MVC 5 project in VS-2015. What do you want more?  `add DB -> Add table -> populate table -> Add model -> Create Controller` but visual studio does not use the Database initially used to create the Model Controller, it simply seems to create a new database out of thin air.

Comment: @user1666620 But why are the tags incorrect? Sorry I am rather new to MVC. But I am attempting to get a `MODEL` -> `VIEW` -> `CONTROLLER` where MODEL is a SQL table and VIEW is a `.cshtml` page. Explain a bit clearer why this is not MVC related?

Comment: @MennoGouw the problem doesn't seem to be with the MVC setup itself - the problem seems to be with how the dbcontext is generated. It's more of a code-first problem.

Comment: Exactly. It is purely a "I have a problem with entity framework dbcontext". The rest is a demonstration of lack of competence or lack of willingness to work on providing a minimal code example. You can remove all the MVC stuff and the problem stays exactly the same.

Comment: @user1666620 I still don't understand. `DbContact` is used to link a database set to a model and a `model` is directly related to the `M` of mvc. Maybe I'm looking at it too simple, sorry for that.

Comment: @MennoGouw the problem isn't with the `M` in MVC. It's with how you are creating the dbcontext which is used by the model. Not anything to do with the model itself.

Comment: @TomTom First you ask for the steps to reproduce the problem. Now you are asking me to remove these steps? Since you seem competent, isn't it much easier for you to filter out the real problem, instead of me erasing the steps to reproduce the problem as someone who is new to creating a MVC project?

Comment: No. I prefer you to show your work not demonstrating ignorance towards site rules.

Comment: @MennoGouw TomTom is just throwing his toys out of the pram because you used the wrong tags, and he's not being particularly helpful about it.

Comment: @tomtom Would this be better? I havent wrote a single line of code yet accept the model class. Since it does not seem to be about the Model itself I left that out and left only the DbContext.

Comment: Now we can start helping. Amazing how little is left now.

Comment: @TomTom I would be baffled if a answer comes out of this. Since I am pretty sure those lines are correct. So baffle me :D

Comment: I am sorry to say - My solution is to avoid the problem. THis is a "known issue" and it is ridiculously disturbing. Comes up regularly.

Comment: @TomTom perhaps you can link me to all those question with the same issues since I cannot find a single one.

Comment: @user1666620 Perhaps you can have another look at my edits, I have posted a video about my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just the connection string in your `Web.config`. When you create a `DbContext` from an existing database outside of your project, Visual Studio prompts

> The connection you selected uses a local data file that is not in the
>   current project. Would you like to copy the file to your project and
>   modify the connection?

If you select Yes, this copies the database file into your project, sets its Build Action to Content, sets a relative reference to it in your connection string and sets it to copy to your output directory on build.

If you modify the `connectionString` in your `Web.config` to point to the correct database you should be set (for future reference, answer No when asked if you want to copy it, unless that is really what you want to do - e.g. for a database file you're distributing with your binaries).

As an example, see the two connections listed below. You would see something like `ProjectContext` if you selected Yes, or something like `ExternalContext` if you selected No.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ExternalContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=C:\Programming\.Net\DataVisualization\Data\DataVisualization\App_Data\Database.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Note that the actual syntax of the `connectionString` may be different in your app depending on settings used, but the key part is the `|DataDirectory|` reference vs the correct path. The path is what you'd need to modify.

Comment: I am not getting that message at al. Apart from that I am using only one connection string which is working for the account database. I simply added a table there that represents the model and the Controller hooks into it. But when I run the app it somehow wants to create a new Database.

Comment: It's likely some other mechanism setting along the lines TomTom mentioned then. You may be able to get it to use the correct database by modifying your `Web.config` as mentioned above though. What connection string(s) are you seeing in your `Web.config`?

Comment: `connectionString="Data Source=...\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataVisualization;Integrated Security=True"` the accounts works with this as well without a problem. But whenever I try to add my own Table, Model and Controller for it EF creates a new database with table to hold the records

Comment: I'm not sure then. I wouldn't want to start taking guesses which might break your existing functionality.

Comment: I have no functionality. I am exactly doing what I was doing yesterday: this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_models.asp which worked in a breeze with a local MSSQL server instead of a local compact one. It showed me the movies and I could add movies and everything just worked. I have repeated my steps at least 10 times, messed around with the connection factory and tried different models and controllers all result in generating a seperate database, EXCEPT for the account functionality that is build into MVC by default.

Comment: The only thing I am doing differently since a couple of hours is using a MSSQL SERVER on @tomtom advice. However this yields the same result, only the additinal database that is being created will spawn in the server I am running.

Comment: How simple can it be, adding the Model and Controller is just one page on that tutorial. And neither do I find all those similar problems @tomtom is talking about, I think I should revert all the edits to the orignal question where I describe each step. Although this was before server migration I have the exact same issues.

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand solution is this:

```
public class LinkedDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LinkedData> LinkedData { get; set; }
    public LinkedDataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

I was assuming it would take the default connection if there was no connection named after the context. The reason was that I did not get a error so the connections would have been fine. Yet without specifying a connectionString in `web.config` it just seem to take part of the default string, since it does find my database and throws in it's namespace and creates a new database out of thin air. I might be new to MVC but I find this ridiculous default behavior. So I still have no clue what the idea behind this is.

Unless you want to have a couple of hundred connection strings for a fairly sized application the only way to go seems to be to call the parent constructor and specify the `DefaultConnection` there. Kind of ironic you have to "specify" default behavior.

Unlike what @tomtom told me, in almost 10 hours I did not find a single scenario that resembles mine. Maybe I was not clear but in my initial post I did specify each step I took. Using a MSSQL SERVER does not seem to be necessary.

Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score -1):

STANDARD BEHAVIOR. As bad as it is. Your db template is copied to the runtime every time you hit the "debug" button, so you always start with a new datababase. Painfull as hell. Not sure how other's solve this - I never use this side of visual studio, I have a sql server installed and create my databases there manually. Makes sure i am always working against a defined copy. Obviously VS has no rights to create databases there ;)

If you bother using google or the site search a little you find tons of similar questions - this is a standard problem people regularly get trapped in because it is totally not what they expect.

(if you ask me, the whole db maintenance side of EF is broken anyway, including the "migrations" that hardly can use SQL Server most basic features).

Comment: I have searched my bum off. But I was not aware it was a EF problem so searching for "VS putting data in different database" does not yield much related stuff. But I had this working yesterday when I was running a tutorial, is this something that just sometimes happens?

Comment: Really no idea, mostly because while I deal with databases every day for years, I never bought into those automatisms. I do complex & sometimes large database work. Environmental full control always was critical, so I never bought into those automatisms. But a lot of people acutally have probems with visual studio database management behavior in debugging. As I said - I bypass those.

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking into my problem. I will probably do the same, I used SQL server many years ago so that would not be a big issue I guess. But that also means that I should probably also migrate the user account database that comes with MVC. I leave this open for now, and see if another answer comes in. I really don't need full control.

Comment: IMHO you should definitely migrate. I love Visual Studio - but some parts (and this is one of the top) are EXTREMELY inconvenient.

Comment: I have migrated the Account database succesfully. But I have the exact same problem with my custom table. I added the exact same table to the MSSQL database. When I register using the MVC template my MSSQL database gets populated. When I create a record from the view generated by the controller it is being inserted into a separate local database within VS. So what is really going on here?